# How to change maker in scatter plot in Julia

Tags: plot, julia, scatter

I would like to change the marker style of a 2D scatter plot based on the value in a vector, ultimately displaying 3 dimensions on two axes. Below is what I'd like to do and the error I get when I try it.

```
x = rand(1:30,100)
y = rand(20:30,100)
MyMarker = [fill("o",50);fill("x",50)]
scatter(x,y,marker=MyMarker,alpha=0.5)

LoadError: PyError (:PyObject_Call) <type 'exceptions.ValueError'>
ValueError(u"Unrecognized marker style ['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']",)
  File "/home/lara/.julia/v0.4/Conda/deps/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3251, in scatter
    edgecolors=edgecolors, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lara/.julia/v0.4/Conda/deps/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1812, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lara/.julia/v0.4/Conda/deps/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 3877, in scatter
    marker_obj = mmarkers.MarkerStyle(marker)
  File "/home/lara/.julia/v0.4/Conda/deps/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/markers.py", line 171, in __init__
    self.set_marker(marker)
  File "/home/lara/.julia/v0.4/Conda/deps/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/markers.py", line 252, in set_marker
    ' {0}'.format(marker))

while loading In[91], in expression starting on line 1

 in getindex at /home/lara/.julia/v0.4/PyCall/src/PyCall.jl:228
 in pysequence_query at /home/lara/.julia/v0.4/PyCall/src/conversions.jl:717
 [inlined code] from /home/lara/.julia/v0.4/PyCall/src/conversions.jl:733
 in pytype_query at /home/lara/.julia/v0.4/PyCall/src/conversions.jl:762
 in convert at /home/lara/.julia/v0.4/PyCall/src/conversions.jl:782
 in pycall at /home/lara/.julia/v0.4/PyCall/src/PyCall.jl:363
 in call at /home/lara/.julia/v0.4/PyCall/src/PyCall.jl:372
 in close_queued_figs at /home/lara/.julia/v0.4/PyPlot/src/PyPlot.jl:401
```

I have tried the following, neither of which is exactly what I want to do but they are close enough, and neither works.

```
using Plots
pyplot(size=(400,200), legend=false)  # set backend and set some session defaults
scatter(rand(30),m = ColorGradient([:red,:green,:blue]),zcolor = repmat([0,0.5,1],10))

using Plots
pyplot(size=(400,200), legend=false)  # set backend and set some session defaults
scatter(rand(30),
        m = ColorGradient([:red,:green,:blue]),  # colors are defined by a gradient
        zcolor = repmat([0,0.5,1],10) # sample from the gradient, cycling through: 0, 0.5, 1
       )
```

Can anyone tell me how to make **marker** take in a vector?

Update
I have a work around but I don't like having to do this: dividing the data into separate sets and then plotting them on the same axes:

```
PyPlot.plot(spacerdataActualSpacer[:Length],spacerdataActualSpacer[:Curvature],marker="x",".")
PyPlot.plot(spacerdataNoActualSpacer[:Length],spacerdataNoActualSpacer[:Curvature],marker="o",".")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's a few different things you can try (I'm on Plots dev, so I can't be certain what will work for you out of the box):

```
scatter(rand(30), group = repmat(1:3,10), marker=:auto)
scatter(rand(30), group = repmat(1:3,10), shape=[:+ :o :utri])
scatter(rand(30), group = repmat(1:3,10), shape=[:+ :o :utri], layout=(3,1))
```

Let me know if any of that is what you want.  To be honest I'm not totally sure I know what your ideal viz will look like.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately none of them work. My ideal plot would look like the one I gave above, but without the need to write a line of code for each marker type. I'd like to be able to specify the marker type using a key. So for example My data might be X = 30 points, Y = 30 points and MarkerStyle = 30 points where each point is the marker style I want to use for the corresponding XY point on the plot.

Comment: If you don't use `group`, pyplot doesn't make it easy to pass a list of shapes.  However I might have discovered a solution with a quick search, and I added an issue for it: https://github.com/tbreloff/Plots.jl/issues/278.  Also can you tell me what "doesn't work" with the examples I provided?  Try `Pkg.checkout("Plots","dev")` and let me know if it works then?

Comment: Here is what I did:      Pkg.checkout("Plots","dev")         INFO: Checking out Plots dev...
INFO: Pulling Plots latest dev...
LoadError: unknown package RecipesBase required by Plots
while loading In[3], in expression starting on line 1

 in error at ./error.jl:21
 in requirements at ./pkg/query.jl:11
 in resolve at ./pkg/entry.jl:404
 in resolve at pkg/entry.jl:404
 in anonymous at pkg/entry.jl:198
 in transact at pkg/git.jl:97
 in _checkout at pkg/entry.jl:190
 in checkout at pkg/entry.jl:205
 in anonymous at pkg/dir.jl:31

Comment: continued error message  in cd at file.jl:22
 in cd at pkg/dir.jl:31

Comment: when I just try to run the 3 lines for scatter plot you suggest, I get the error that LoadError: PyError (:PyObject_Call) <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>
TypeError('scatter() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)',)

while loading In[4], in expression starting on line 1

Comment: They worked for me.  After checking out Plots dev again, also do `Pkg.add("RecipesBase"); Pkg.checkout("RecipesBase"); using Plots` in a clean session.  I'll be tagging a 0.7 version of Plots soon... until then you'll have to track development if you want the latest and greatest.

Comment: Plots and PyPlot have had new versions tagged since this question. Has this fixed your error @user3061923?

Comment: How can I produce a different figure each time I produce a `scatter`? At the moment it behaves as if I use `!` where there is an overlay